# SQL Server 2012: Dynamically identifying the user name who is executing a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How to identify the user name who is executing a stored procedure.

For instance, I have stored procedure called 'GetEmployeeDetails'.
For this SP, I would have granted execute access to N number of users like

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON GetEmployeeDetails TO User1
GRANT EXECUTE ON GetEmployeeDetails TO User2
GRANT EXECUTE ON GetEmployeeDetails TO User3
```

How to identify whether User1 or User2 or User3 is executing the SP?

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but the answer pointed to is incomplete, because it doesn't mention the ORIGINAL_LOGIN() function, which is the only way to find out the login name of the connected user, if there was an execution context switch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`SUSER_NAME()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) which returns the login identification name of the currently connected user.

Similarly you can as well use `SUSER_ID()` which returns login identification number of the currently connected user.